# SpTBX: remove TabControl thin frame

Tags: delphi, sptbxlib

`TSpTbxTabControl` has thin frame around child memo. [image: frame]

Can i somehow hide this frame- only show tab header and child memo of course.
Better w/o using `TSpTbxTabSet` but using tab control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done by adding an OnDrawBackground event to the component, like so:

```
procedure TForm3.SpTBXTabControl1DrawBackground(Sender: TObject;
  ACanvas: TCanvas; ARect: TRect; const PaintStage: TSpTBXPaintStage;
  var PaintDefault: Boolean);
begin
  if (PaintStage = pstPrePaint) then
  begin
    PaintDefault := False;
  end;
end;
```

You will also need to add SpTbxSkins to the forms interface uses.

This will provide you with the following look:
[image]

I would suggest though that you remove the border from the TMemo control instead of the tab border as this will provide a better "Look and Feel" to what your trying to do.

Comment: Good- only i see white border now. http://shot.qip.ru/008s9h-3QODkgRBy/ . Can i expand memo a little by x/y?

Comment: Added `    CurrentSkin.PaintBackground(ACanvas, ARect, skncDock,sknsNormal, true, false);`, better.

Comment: @Alextp - Glad you got the white border sorted